# How to get the last record of the table and update a column value and insert to the same column with new record using angularJs/Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, angularjs, json.net

I am working in Web Api & MVC using angularjs for CURD operations,
In my DB I have a table "Accounts" it has a column with Name "ID" which will insert as 
1 for first record and 2 for second record etc... 
This column values will increment as per the last record in table,
this process should be in client side only.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just don't do this. If you want a magical incremental number you should use an identity value or a sequence. Any other approach is going to have some major problems with concurrency. Honestly, if you are using magic numbers like this the end user probably shouldn't even know what the value is.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to send next ID from db to client, create a new record on client with that ID and update it in db.

1) All you need to do is to create a empty record in db and send it's id/primary key to the client.  This approach has a potential problem that, if the client stops/chooses to cancel the operation, there will be lot of empty records created.

2) Otherwise, you can fetch the last record from client using `select max(id) from table` and then use id+1 for the new record. The problem with this approach is that when multiple clients try to update db at the same time, all of them will/may have the same id.

3) In order to overcome the problem of (2), you can use locking mechanisms, but thats not how you do it. Its not worth it.

In my opinion, in most of the cases, **client doesn't need to know the id of the going to be created record**. Once the record is created, you can send it from db.

Answer (score 0):

Once you're within the table, do everything in there. It's faster an easier.

UPDATE table1 SET column = (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(id) FROM Accounts WHERE user = ? GROUP BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ) WHERE user = ?